# True parameter in null hypothesis testing

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, hypothesis-testing, inference

In a null hypothesis, if our parameter in a linear model is θ = 0, wouldn't that mean the true parameter of θ is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we do a hypothesis test, we typically write the null hypothesis like $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$, yes.

However, that is just what we posit under the null hypothesis. That has no bearing on what the true value of $\theta$ is. The true value of $\theta$ is whatever it is, whether or not we hypothesis test or even think about it at all!

Comment: @user368584 It is incorrect to assume that your estimated value is the spot-on right value, but that is your best guess at the true value, in some sense, yes.

Comment: +1 To add an "applied" example, you might wish to test that the expected number of points from tossing a die is three, $\theta=3$. If you test a fair die (but you do not know that it is, which is why you do hypothesis testing), the true value would be 3.5. Quite simply if we knew the true value, there would be no point in doing hypthesis tests in the first place!